# Fibonacci sequence for n > 46 Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have the following code which provides the correct values for n < 47.

```
public static int fib(int n) {
    int nthTerm = 0;
    if (n == 2)
        nthTerm = 1;
    else {
        double goldenRatio = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
        nthTerm = (int) (Math.round(Math.pow(goldenRatio, n)
                - Math.pow(1 - goldenRatio, n)) / Math.sqrt(5));

        if (n % 2 == 1 && n < 45)
            nthTerm++;
    }
    return nthTerm;
}
```

Any value for n > 46 is out of int range. How could I adapt this approach to work for n > 46?

P.S. I know of BigInteger but am not very adept at it so I would appreciate an example using BigInteger, too.

Comment: Use `long` in place of `int`.

Comment: Or `BigInteger` to support values outside the range of `long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for transformated code into BigInteger.

```
package your.pack

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 * Created on 3/6/16.
 */
public class Fibonacci {

    private static BigDecimal goldenRatio = new BigDecimal((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2);
    private static BigDecimal goldenRatioMin1 = goldenRatio.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
    private static BigDecimal sqrt5 = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(5));

    private static BigInteger fib(int n) {
        BigInteger nthTerm = new BigInteger("0");
        if (n == 2)
            nthTerm = BigInteger.ONE;
        else {
            BigDecimal minResult = goldenRatio.pow(n).subtract(goldenRatioMin1.pow(n));
            nthTerm = minResult.divide(sqrt5,0).toBigInteger();

            if (n % 2 == 1 && n < 45){
                nthTerm = nthTerm.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }

        }
        return nthTerm;
    }

    private static int fib2(int n) {
        int nthTerm = 0;
        if (n == 2)
            nthTerm = 1;
        else {
            double goldenRatio = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
            nthTerm = (int) (Math.round(Math.pow(goldenRatio, n)
                    - Math.pow(1 - goldenRatio, n)) / Math.sqrt(5));

            if (n % 2 == 1 && n < 45)
                nthTerm++;
        }
        return nthTerm;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(
                fib(47)
        );
    }

}
```

Method fib2 is your code, fib is the transformed into BigInteger. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `long` instead of using `int`, and remember to cast the value from `Math.round()` to `long` as well (by writing `(long) Math.round(...)` just as you casted to `int`) .

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use `int` is because `fib(47)` is `2971215073` which overflows Java's signed 32-bit `int` ([2<sup>31</sup>-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)). You could use a [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) *optimization* to implement it with [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) like,

```
private static Map<Integer, BigInteger> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    memo.put(0, BigInteger.ZERO);
    memo.put(1, BigInteger.ONE);
}

public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    BigInteger v = fib(n - 2).add(fib(n - 1));
    memo.put(n, v);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: For better performance, just do the `get()` and check for `null`, so `n` doesn't have to be boxed twice, and to only perform one hash lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `long`, you support perfectly the range over 1000; but if you want support all possible value then you need use `BigInteger`.

A example use `long`:

```
public static long fib(int n) 
{
    long f0 = 1;
    long f1 = 1;

    long c = 2;

    while(c < n)
    {
        long tmp = f0+f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = tmp;
        c++;
    }

    return f1;
}
```